# Controller.Json() is appending junk symbols (like question mark) in JsonResult

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am using Controller.Json(). But in the JsonResult, my data is appended with junk data. It used to work properly in VS2013, but is giving such issue in VS2015.

**Output something like this:**

`[{"TotalRowCount":6,"TotalPageCount":1,"GridData":[{"LocationId":55,"Location_Name":"asd","Country":null,"State":null,"City":null,"Pin_Code":null,"Created_By":27,"Updated_By":27,"Created_Date":null,"Updated_Date":"\/Date(1438338668570)\/","Is_Active":false,"SectionCount":1,"Section_Mst_List":null,"FTPServer":null,"FTPUserName":null,"FTPPassword":null,"MG_LoginId":null,"MG_Password":null,"MG_HardwareId":null}]]���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������`

*Hence, it gives parse error in javascript (Syntax error: Unexpected token)*

**CS code:**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetLocationMaster(Location_Mst location, int rows, int page, string sidx, string sord)
{
    GridDataResult gridDataResult = repo.GetLocationMaster(location, rows, page, sidx, sord);
    List<GridDataResult> lst = new List<GridDataResult>();
    lst.Add(gridDataResult);

    JsonResult jr = Json(lst.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return jr;
}
```

**JavaScript AJAX call:**

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetLocationMaster", "Location")';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {}
}).fail(
    function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
        alert(err);
   });
```

Comment: Have you lokoed at *exactly* what's on the wire in something like Wireshark?

Comment: Where did you get the output from? What about a Fiddler trace (easier to use than Wireshark) ?

Comment: Thanks Jon and Steve. I tried a Fiddler Trace, but it showed proper response without any junk. Am I missing a plugin or something, since the code used to run properly in Visual Studio 2013??

Comment: where are you seeing this extra grabage at?

Comment: Adam, I'm seeing it in the response to my API call.

Comment: I think the question Adam asked was at what point are you seeing the garbage? If you stop with the debugger on lst.ToArray(), do you see the garbage? If not, maybe after the "jr" variable? I suspect it is a "utf-8" issue

Comment: @ZivWeissman Nope. Not in the code. When I'm returning the 'jr' variable, it is proper (without any junk). I get the junk only in the browser. I investigated this using the 'Postman' chrome plugin. In its 'Raw' view, it shows the junk, but in its 'Preview' it ignores the junk.